# Перебор возможных вариантов интерфейса boolean

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, typescript

Я имею следующий интерфейс

```
interface test {
value1: boolean;
value2: boolean;
value3: boolean;
/*...*/}
```

Каким путём легче всего создать его реализации с каждым возможным вариантом?

Comment: Проще всего вложить три цикла.

Comment: Интерфейс в будущем будет дополняться, может есть какой-нибудь инструмент для таких целей?

Comment: А просто получать в цикле из значений от 0 до 2^n-1 (n - количество полей)?

Comment: Это плохой интерфейс. Если отказаться от него в пользу булева массива, то можно написать универсальный алгоритм перебора комбинаций всех бит.

Comment: Я думаю можно создать одну реализацию такого интерфейса и уже перебрать её как массив boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Это работает:

```
interface someInterface {
    someValue1: boolean;
    someValue2: boolean;
    someValue3: boolean;
}

function logAllCombinations(o: any) {
    const objectProperties = Object.keys(o);
    const combinationsCount = Math.pow(2, objectProperties.length);

    for(let i = 0; i < combinationsCount; i++) { 
        for(let j = 0; j < objectProperties.length; j++) {
            o[objectProperties[j]] = Boolean((i >> j) & 1);
        }

        console.log(o);
    }
}

const interfaceObject: someInterface = {
    someValue1: false,
    someValue2: false,
    someValue3: false
};

logAllCombinations(interfaceObject);
```

Вывод:

```
{ someValue1: false, someValue2: false, someValue3: false }
{ someValue1: true, someValue2: false, someValue3: false }
{ someValue1: false, someValue2: true, someValue3: false }
{ someValue1: true, someValue2: true, someValue3: false }
{ someValue1: false, someValue2: false, someValue3: true }
{ someValue1: true, someValue2: false, someValue3: true }
{ someValue1: false, someValue2: true, someValue3: true }
{ someValue1: true, someValue2: true, someValue3: true }
```